# SQLCMD runs in CMD but error in vbs

Tags: t-sql, vbscript, sqlcmd

The following code runs at the CMD line, but get error "Expected end of statement", Line: 1 Char 11.

sqlcmd -S DONALDLT-PC\SQLEXPRESS -E -i C:\SQL\append_ToTblPurchaseDetials.sql

Comment: Is that the only line in your vbs file?

Comment: Post complete code

Answer (score 1):

Its failing because your syntax is incorrect. You can not execute shell scripts directly in visual basic. The statements/parameters need to be properly escaped and passed to some type of execute method. If you are already doing this, please add the entire code.

Comment: Jason, Thank you for your feedback. I put it in a .bat and ran it successfully.                                                                                   
@echo off
SQLCMD.exe -S DONALDLT-PC\SQLEXPRESS -d AdventureWorks2014 -E -Q "Execute pr_AppendToPurchaseOrderDetail_new"